# Is there always a permutation whose adjacent elements have composite sum?

Tags: combinatorics

For n>=7 is it always possible to find a permutation of the numbers from 1 to n such that the sum of any two adjacent elements of the permutation is a composite number?

For example: the permutation 1,3,5,4,6,2,7 has 1+3=4, 3+5=8, 5+4=9, 4+6=10, 6+2=8,2+7=9, and 7+1=8.

Comment: Place the odd numbers together first.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as Douglas Zare said in the comment, place all of the odd numbers first.  Then all of the adjacent sums are even (and bigger than 2), except for the sum of the last odd and the first even.  We can choose these to be, say, 5 and 4 so that this sum is composite.

This method also works for $n=5,6$ giving permutations like 1 3 5 4 2 and 1 5 3 6 4 2.

Comment: Almost, but not quite – from the example OP works out, it's intended that the first and last numbers be treated as adjacent, so their sum is to be composite as well. This rules out $n=5$, but $n=6$ can be salvaged with 5 1 3 6 2 4.